# Leftover Razor partial tag helper in page source of all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, source-code

While randomly browsing through the page source of Stack Overflow, I came across a closing `</partial>` tag in the page source of Stack Overflow. I went ahead and checked the page source of a few Stack Exchange sites and it seems that this is the case for all pages of all Stack Exchange sites.

This looks like a leftover part of [Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Razor) markup, specifically the [partial tag helper](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0). The partial tag helper is a self-closing tag:

```
<partial name="_Xyz" />
```

and it may have been used like an opening and closing tag:

```
<partial name=_Xyz"></partial>
```

And what we see on the source page is the closing tag.

It may also be that a partial view intended to be included is not being included in the page markup.

[image: Partial tag in the source of Meta Stack Exchange]

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + H - Find `</partial>` Replace: `​`. Ship It! 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All instances of this issue has been fixed across the codebase, thanks for the heads up! The developer(s) that added these hadn't realized that the  [tag helper](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0) was implemented as self-closing only, which means that .net happily renders `<partial ...></partial>` as `<!-- partial code here --></partial>`. The fix was simple - remove the closing partial tags.